# Can DialogFlow fulfillment text be rich?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've built a webhook for DialogFlow intent fulfillment.  Is there any way to include formatting in the text responses provided by the web hook?  Ideally I'd like to bold, italicize, make links, and add newlines.  Especially newlines.

I've tried including `\n` in my response, but no joy.

Answer (score 2):

Actions on Google supports a limited subset of markdown in the cards, but only the new line in the Simple Response.

- **new line with a double space followed by \n**
- `**bold**`
- `*italics*`

More info in [documentation - responses](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card).

Comment: I'm not strictly using Actions-On-Google.  Dialogflow and AoG tend to be conflated unnecessarily.  I'm anticipating a large percentage of inquiries to come from an embedded web agent.  Dialogflow's test embed did not parse the formatting you suggested for AoG (which isn't a complaint about your answer - just noting for posterity)

Comment: @Pickle Sorry, as far as I know, there is no way to do that in just Dialogflow.